# HTML navbar with two image hyperlinks

Tags: html, css, navbar, nav

I've been trying to create a responsive navbar with just two images (which are hyperlinks and transparent) and I can't seem to get the formatting right. The way I want it to look is:

- First image: width:60%
- Second image: width: 40%
- Both have the same height
- Border: 2px solid black (around both images)
- Padding: 10px (Around both images and between the two)
- Keep the navbar on the top of the page
- Hover effect that changes the background color

[Basic Idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXB39.png)

The closest I've come is this code:

HTML:

```
<head>
    <div id="outerdiv" class="navbar-fixed-top">
         <a href="index.php"><img id="image1" src="image1.png"  alt="Find"/></a>
         <a href="add.php" > <img id="image2" src="image2.png" alt="Add"/></a>
    </div>
</head>
```

CSS:

```
 <style>
    img{
        display:inline-block;
        border: 2px solid black;
        background-color:#499FE2;    
    }
    img:hover{
        background-color: #91BCEE;
    }

    #image1{
        width:60%;
        float:left;
    }

    #image2{
       width:40%;
       float:left;
    }

    #outerdiv{
       background-color: #black ;
    }

    a{
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

The main problem I'm having is that I cannot figure out where to implement the padding so that it will separate the two images and surround them.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to clean up you HTML code into valid HTML so that your CSS selectors are able to apply styles to the elements in the DOM. Remove the backslashes from your HMTL code to give you this;

```
<head>
<div id="outerdiv" class="navbar-fixed-top">
     <a href="index.php"><img id="image1" src="image1.png"  alt="Find"/></a>
     <a href="add.php" > <img id="image2"   src="image2.png" alt="Add"/></a>
</div>
</head>
```

Add a -4px left-margin to the images to counter the space used by the borders (this prevents the second image from going to next line since they occupy 60% + 40% of the entire page width, yet right + left borders of images take up 4px).

Also add display:block; property to the "#outerdiv" selector and change the value of the display property for the "a" selector to inline.

```
img{
    display:inline-block;
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color:#499FE2;
    margin-left:-4px;
}
img:hover{
    background-color: #91BCEE;
}

#image1{
    width:60%;
    float:left;
}

#image2{
   width:40%;
   float:left;
}

#outerdiv{
   background-color:black;
   display: block;
}

a{
    display: inline;
}
```

see working snippet

```css
 img{
        display:inline-block;
        border: 2px solid black;
        background-color:#499FE2;
        margin-left:-4px;
    }
    img:hover{
        background-color: #91BCEE;
    }

    #image1{
        width:60%;
        float:left;
    }

    #image2{
       width:40%;
       float:left;
    }

    #outerdiv{
       background-color:black;
       display: block;
    }

    a{
        display: inline;
    }
```

```html
<head>
    <div id="outerdiv" class="navbar-fixed-top">
         <a href="index.php"><img id="image1" src="image1.png"  alt="Find"/></a>
         <a href="add.php" > <img id="image2"   src="image2.png" alt="Add"/></a>
    </div>
</head>
```

Comment: I forgot to take out the backslashes in the code but they were there because I'm using PHP, sorry if that caused confusion. The code you provided doesn't implement padding around the images, which is what I'm primarily struggling with. Thank you for the help though!